# How does PySide/PyQt QMainWindow close a QDockWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I need to know how the QDockWidget is normally closed. I have a serial port/thread attached to a QDockWidget, and I need to make sure the thread and serial port close properly.

```
class SerialDock(QDockWidget):
    ...

    def close(self):
        print("Close")
        self.serialport.close()
        self.thread.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("closeEvent")
        self.serialport.close()
        self.thread.close()
```

The close and closeEvents are not called when I click the QMainWindow X button. Do I have to call the close method from the QMainWindow close? The only way I know to solve this is to use the QApplication.aboutToQuit signal, and I really don't want to have to remember to set that for one specific widget. How does the QDockWidget get destroyed or closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `destroyed` signal in the `QDockWidget`:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui as ui
import PyQt4.QtCore as core

app = ui.QApplication([])

mw = ui.QMainWindow()
mw.setCentralWidget(ui.QTextEdit())

dw = ui.QDockWidget("Test",mw)
dw.setWidget(ui.QLabel("Content"))

mw.addDockWidget(core.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dw)

def onDestroy(w):
    print("Do stuff here")
    print(w)

dw.destroyed.connect(onDestroy)

mw.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: This works, but I get the signal too late for closing my other items.